# Focus in DataGrid after Sort

Tags: c#

I have a DataGrid whith two columns and with both options CanUserSort. 
How do I return the focus to the cell of a DataGrid after clicking on the header?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which cell you want to get focus, but after having a reference to it (by `Items`, `Items` for example) you can set [Focus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.focus(v=vs.110).aspx). (I think it works similarly for WPF, ... too.)

EDIT: an example code:

```
if (grid[0].Count > 0) {
    grid[0][0].Focus();//Or the one you prefer
}
```